# Spring Data JPA with QueryDSL, Count issue with aggregate function

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am using Spring Data JPA with QueryDSL and trying to use Sum function in where condition, As i am using pagination so i have to get count first.
So i have java code like below :-

```
NumberPath<Double> path = entityPath.getNumber("qty", Double.class);
BooleanExpression exp = path.sum().loe(120);        
JPQLQuery countQuery = from(stock).where(exp);
long count = countQuery.count();
```

its creating query like this :-

```
select count(stock0_.stock_id) as col_0_0_ from stock stock0_ 
where sum(stock0_.qty)>=120;
```

and i am getting `Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function`.

above query is not working in `SQL` as well because sum function cant be use with count in where condition. I have not idea how to deal with such problem when i have to get count first and then fetch the real data. 
Can someone please help me out with what is `JPA` approach to deal with such issue.

Please don't suggested `@Query` annotation because i can not use it. Due to dynamic filtration requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using aggregate functions (sum). Then you need having() instead where()

This example is a really large one. You only need to care about pagination and having elements.

If you got different **predicates** and a **pageRequest** object.

Page request example:

```
pageRequest = new PageRequest(
                MI_PAGE, 
                LIMIT, 
                Sort.Direction.valueOf( ASC ), 
                ORDER_FIELD);
```

EntityQ represents a QueryDSL generated meta-entity.

Query example:

```
new JPAQuery(em).from(entityQ).where( entityQ.id.in(

        new JPASubQuery()
        .from(entity2Q).innerJoin(entity2Q.objEntityQ, entityQ)
            .where(ENTITY, PREDICATE)                           
            .groupBy(entity2Q.objEntityQ.id)
            .having( Wildcard.count.goe(SIZE) )                 
        .list(entity2Q.objEntityQ.id)

    ))
    .offset(pageRequest.getOffset() )
    .limit( pageRequest.getPageSize() ) 
    .orderBy(ORDERS).list(entityQ);
```

**EDIT 2** *More specific for your example*:

I usually have a persistence context in my custom repositories:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em
```

Then, you could create a simple JPAQuery:

```
new JPAQuery(em)
.from(YOUR_STOCK_QUERYDSL_ENTITY)
.groupBy(YOUR_STOCK_QUERYDSL_ENTITY.field_to_sum)
.having(YOUR_STOCK_QUERYDSL_ENTITY.field_to_sum.sum().as("alias")
.goe(100));
```

Comment: where sum(stock0_.qty)>=120 is a group function. This should work with a having() comparison or use a JPASubquery.

Comment: can you please explain me in detail or provide any link. How to use that with pagable

Comment: I am using Using spring org.springframework.data.domain.Pagable class, for pagination. look like Above example using two different table.

Comment: How can i run below query in querydsl :- 
`select count(*) as count  from (select count(stock0_.stock_id) as col_0_0_ from 
stock stock0_  having sum(stock0_.QTY)>=100) tbl;`

Comment: Definitely, the final query implementation is not a part of the first question. Your error was a common misunderstanding of query aggregation in QueryDSL. If possible, mark the answer as valid if it was helpful for you.

Comment: do you know how to run above query with querydsl ?